# On safe constructor technique in Java

Tags: java, oop, lambda, constructor

I have read IBM [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) about safe constructor techniques in Java. Main idea of the article that you shouldn't explicitly or implicitly expose *this* reference in constructor. But there is nothing mentioned about lambdas. As far as I know lambdas capture local context (only final or effectively final variables), so if you refer any class method inside lambda body then *this* reference is exposed?

My question is following: is it a good practice to design classes which accepts `Runnable`, `Function`, `Predicate` as argument in constructor? If you pass simple lambda (doesn't refer class methods) to such constructor then there is nothing wrong as I understand but on the other hand it provides the way to pass anonymous inner class as argument as a result *this* reference may be exposed.

```java
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB classB;

    public ClassA() {
        // fine
        classB = new ClassB(integer -> integer % 2 == 0);
        // oops
        classB = new ClassB(new Function<Integer, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(Integer integer) {
                return integer % 2 == 0;
            }
        });
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    private final Function<Integer, Boolean> function;

    public ClassB(Function<Integer, Boolean> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question and added small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it a good practice to design classes which accepts `Runnable`, `Function`,  `Predicate` as argument in constructor?

Yes, as any other object. As long as you are not exposing a `this` reference you can pass whatever you want to a constructor.

In the case of your example `ClassA` is broken, while `ClassB` is thread safe. You are implicitly letting a `this` reference escape from `ClassA` (parent object) by creating a inner anonymous class in its constructor and passing it to another object. But the class (`ClassB`) that has the `Function` parameter is safely constructed.

Comment: So is my understanding correct that ClassB is not responsible for the way in which it is constructed by parent class, right? If classB is a part of the framework and classA is a part of application then it's application developer fault.

Comment: No matter what you pass to `ClassB` constructor, it is always safely published. The problem here is `ClassA`. Should you move your code out of `ClassA` constructor it would be safely constructed as well.

Answer (score 0):

> > is it a good practice to design classes which accepts Runnable

If you look at `java.lang.Thread` you can find such constructor

```
public Thread(Runnable target) {}
```

The answer is `yes`, even Oracle does it.

Comment: Yes, you are right but as I can see it was introduced in JDK 1.0. Things could change since that time. For example some classes and methods from JDK 1.0 have been deprecated.

Comment: I agree with you! But then again, if Oracle deprecates smth it puts the `@Deprecated` annotation.